# Remove vertical whitespace between figures

Tags: spacing, graphics

I want to display several images with no whitespace between them. The horizontal whitespace was removed by adding `%` to the end of the `includegraphics` lines. However, there is still a visible space between the image rows (see below).

How do I remove this space automatically?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{example-image}%
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{example-image}%
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{example-image}%
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{example-image}%

    \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image}%
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image}%
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image}%
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image}%
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Use `\offinterlineskip`

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering\offinterlineskip
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{example-image}%
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{example-image}%
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{example-image}%
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{example-image}\\
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image}%
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image}%
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image}%
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image}%
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So the key here is `\offinterlineskip`. Wonderfully simple. Thanks.